# Using EmptyCoroutineContext to getStrng from sharedPreferences

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following class that is used as part of the okhttp interceptor.

I am wondering should I be using Dispatchers.IO or EmptyCoroutineContext.

Does the sharedPreferences use the Dispatchers.IO under the hood when doing something like this: `val token = sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN_KEY, "")` If not then would I need to use the `Dispatchers.IO` and if it does I would be safe to use the `EmptyCoroutineContext` so I won't be launching on another IO dispatcher.

```
class TokenInterceptor(preferenceRepository: PreferenceRepository) : Interceptor {

    private companion object {
        const val AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization"
    }
    private var loginUser: LoginUser? = null

    init {
        CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext).launch {
            loginUser = preferenceRepository.retrieveCurrentUserOrNull()
        }
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, loginUser?.token ?: "")
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the most problematic thing here is not the context, but the fact that the `CoroutineScope` is created on the spot and not assigned to anything, so nobody can ever cancel it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using EmptyCoroutineContext just causes it to use Dispatchers.Default, which isn’t appropriate for IO like reading and writing to disk. When the current CoroutineContext has no dispatcher, it will always have Dispatchers.Default added to it implicitly (hence the name Default).

SharedPreferences is a pure Java class. It only has blocking and asynchronous functions—no coroutine dispatchers.

---

#### Regarding coroutines:

Don’t create a new CoroutineScope that isn’t assigned to any property, because then you aren’t managing its lifecycle. If you truly require your coroutine to not be interrupted by any events in your application (rare situation) then use GlobalScope. The vast majority of cases, your coroutines are going to be related to some piece of your app, maybe a screen the user is interacting with for example. You’re going to want to cancel coroutines that are related to only that piece of your app when it goes out of scope so you aren’t leaking resources. That’s the purpose of creating a CoroutineScope.

---

#### How Android SharedPreferences work

When you first retrieve the SharedPreferences instance, they are loaded in totality to an internal Map in memory from disk synchronously on whatever thread you’re using, so it blocks that thread. Then, every time you read a preference value, it’s just pulling it from the in-memory map so there’s no need to worry about what thread you’re on.

When you write preferences using `edit`, the in-memory Map is immediately updated synchronously. If you use `commit()` the changes are also written to disk synchronously, thereby blocking the current thread. If you use `apply()`, the changes are saved to disk asynchronously.

Since in most cases SharedPreferences are a very small file, we generally just don’t care about the one-time blocking load of the preferences on the main thread, and we do writes using `apply()` to avoid blocking more than we have to, since `commit()` causes main thread hiccups.

In your code above, you apparently already have a SharedPreferences instance internal in your repository. Therefore, reading values is non-blocking and synchronous because it is trivially reading from an in-memory Map.

If you want to avoid all blocking of the main thread, then you could use a coroutine with Dispatchers.IO to load the SharedPreferences instance, but it’s unnecessary to go farther than that. You could use suspend functions for making edits so it could be done such that the function doesn’t return until the change is written to disk. To do it this way, use a suspend function with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and `commit()` the edit.

Or you could use the Jetpack preferences library, which already has a proper coroutine-based API. Supposedly it’s also more stable. It takes a lot more boilerplate to use than SharedPreferences, so that’s something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences are not associated with coroutines, so they do not run Dispatchers.IO under the hood.  If you want to asynchronously fetch data from shared preferences just do something like this in your fragment/activity:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {  //Handle the main logic on the default dispatcher to keep IO as free as possible
    val job = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //get data from preferences and return
    }
    val data = job.await() //wait for completed data fetch
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        //do any UI updates related to data
    }
}
```